# how to install ucas package in macOS

Tags: installing, macos

today when I compile the beamer project, shows error:

```
File `ucas.sty' not found. ^^M
```

then I tried to install the ucas package like this in macOS 12.4, show error:

```
➜  ~ sudo tlmgr install ucas
tlmgr: package repository https://mirrors.sjtug.sjtu.edu.cn/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
tlmgr install: package ucas not present in repository.
tlmgr: action install returned an error; continuing.
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
```

what should I do to fixed this problem? this is the beamer file content:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ctex,hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% other packages
\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath,xcolor,multicol,booktabs,calligra}
\usepackage{graphicx,pstricks,listings,stackengine}

% packages and settings for bibtex
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}
\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny}   % footnote for bibtex
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]   % reference list for bibtex
\defbibheading{reference}{\section*{参考文献}}   % heading for bibtex

\author[马时杰]{马时杰\\{\small name@ia.ac.cn}}
\title{UCAS (CASIA) Beamer Theme}
\subtitle{毕业设计开题报告}
\institute{中国科学院自动化研究所}
%\date{2022年5月24日}
\date{\today}
\usepackage{ucas}

% defs
\def\cmd#1{\texttt{\color{red}\footnotesize $\backslash$#1}}
\def\env#1{\texttt{\color{blue}\footnotesize #1}}
\definecolor{deepblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{deepred}{rgb}{0.6,0,0}
\definecolor{deepgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{halfgray}{gray}{0.55}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{deepblue},
    emphstyle=\ttfamily\color{deepred},    % Custom highlighting style
    stringstyle=\color{deepgreen},
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\small\color{halfgray},
    rulesepcolor=\color{red!20!green!20!blue!20},
    frame=shadowbox,
}


\begin{document}

\kaishu

% \begin{frame}
%     \titlepage
%     \begin{figure}[htpb]
%         \begin{center}
%             \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{fig/UCAS_logo.eps}
%         \end{center}
%     \end{figure}
% \end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
    \begin{figure}[htpb]
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth]{fig/UCAS_logo.eps}\quad\quad\quad\quad
            \includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth]{fig/CASIA_logo.png}
        \end{center}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}   
\begin{frame}
    \tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show,subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide,subsubsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide]
\end{frame}



\section{计划进度}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item 一月：完成文献调研
        \item 二月：复现并评测各种Beamer主题美观程度
        \item 三、四月：美化UCAS (CASIA) Beamer主题
        \item 五月：论文撰写
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

% \section{参考文献}

% \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
%     %\bibliography{ref}
%     \bibliographystyle{alpha}
%     % 如果参考文献太多的话，可以像下面这样调整字体：
%     % \tiny\bibliographystyle{alpha}
% \end{frame}

\begin{frame}{参考文献}
    \printbibliography[heading=reference]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{center}
        {\Huge\calligra Thanks!}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this helpful? https://github.com/zondie17/UCAS_Beamer

Comment: @Dolphin In addition to the comment by @ latexerexetal which tells you where you can find this custom package, you might also have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1167/36296 to see how you can install it (or you can simply place the `.sty` in the same folder as your .tex file)